# proximity sensor cordova doesnt´t works

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I'm using this plugin in Intel XDK

http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/awoken-well/cordova-plugin-proximity
for the job but when I use its provided example 1, when I run it on my device(Android) which have proximity it doesn´t works. Here is the code:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba del sensor de proximidad</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
        @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }          @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
        @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }                   @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }
    </style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="align-center">Sensor de proximidad</h1>
    <p class="align-center">
        Este tipo de sensor se utiliza para evitar los eventos táctiles cuando el dispositivo está cerca de la cara
    </p>


    <script src="cordova.js"></script>          <!-- "Phantom" cordova.js required for projects that use plugins -->

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>           <!-- for your event code, see README and file comments for details -->
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>      <!-- for your init code, see README and file comments for details -->
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>     <!-- normalizes device and document ready events, see file for details -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSuccess(state) {
            alert('Proximity state: ' + (state ? 'near' : 'far'));
        };

        navigator.proximity.enableSensor();

        setInterval(function(){
            navigator.proximity.getProximityState(onSuccess);
        }, 3000);
        /*function hola(){
            alert("hola");
        }
        
        setInterval(function(){
            hola();
        }, 1000);*/
        
    </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Someone can tell me what´s wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the init-app.js file for some code showing a clean way to initialize your app, you need to wait for the device ready event before you can access any plugin code. In other words, the underlying Cordova framework must initialize. This initialization happens in parallel, not sequentially, with the loading of your app, and usually takes longer to do than the loading of your DOM.

In essence, there's a bunch of Cordova native code under the hood that needs to get started, and until it's all ready, your calls to those plugins, which all rely on native code, will fail.